# SQL adding composite primary key through alter table option

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have already created a table to the database.

Table is something like following (I am using sqlite on mac for iPhone dev)

```
create table
(
attendanceDate   varchar,
studentNo        integer,
absentDetail     varchar
);
```

Now I have already committed this statements. What I need is the following:

- Add a composite primary key (attandanceDate,studentNo)
- add a foreign key studentNo

I don't know the alter table syntax in sqlite3.

So, I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLITE3 does not have syntax to do what you want.

From the SQLITE documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

> SQLite supports a limited subset of
>   ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command
>   in SQLite allows the user to rename a
>   table or to add a new column to an
>   existing table. It is not possible to
>   rename a colum, remove a column, or
>   add or remove constraints from a
>   table.

You will need to recreate the table with the composite primary key and foreign key defined.

Comment: If I can't Alter, I can drop & recreate it, is it So?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table you need to create the primary key then. SQLLite3 doesn't support foreign key constraints as far as I know. Check out [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) for more information. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, By R&D.

I think, I should drop my table & recreate the table by following syntax,

---

create table stuAttendance
(
attenDate varchar,
stuNo integer,
absentDesc varchar,
primary key(attenDate,stuNo)
foreign key(stuNo) references stuClass(stuNo)
)

---

That will work as what I needed.